# couchbase.lite link behaviour in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, couchbase-lite

Hello Xamarin developers!
Now I am facing a couchbase.lite problem to integrate in Xamarin.forms ios project.
it crashes the app when link behaviour is "Link Framework sdks only", but "Don't link".
You know to reduce ipa size, we have to choose the "Link Framework sdks only".
I want your opinion.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is very serious problem, I had the same issue, so I insisted to use "don't link" and submitted to store.
I guess that is the Xamarin issue now. will be updated soon.

Comment: then is there any special build option for you to reduce the estimated app store size?

Comment: Really sorry, I just checked all the resources like images and audios , you can set the image optimization but is not helpful so much. Just be sure check all the packages so that unnecessary ones there. and remove them , will help you a little even.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade Xamarin version, or simply you can change your lite form couchbase.lite to sqlite.
sqlite also supports mvvmcross for xamarin.
it's package name is sqlite.net-pcl to find in nuget packages.